# Ngnix configuration load balancer node js server

Tags: node.js, rest, api, nginx, load-balancing

I have developed a Rest API with node js on a machine with ubuntu server 16.04 and on another machine with same SO I have installed Nginx as a reverse proxy. Now I would like to set my Rest API in load balancing deploying my application on two servers.
How can I configure Nginx as a load balancer with to server that exposes the same node js application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit your **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default** according to [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-http-proxying-load-balancing-buffering-and-caching) such as

```
upstream backend_hosts {
   server host1.example.com;
   server host2.example.com;
   server host3.example.com;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.com;

   location / {
      proxy_pass http://backend_hosts;
   }
}
```